# ffmpeg error: Unable to find a suitable output format for '25'

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to convert a large video file and slice it into segments under Windows with x265 encoder via nvenc_hevc using the following command:

`ffmpeg.exe  -y -re  -hwaccel cuvid  -i  "T:\VideoTest\00000.mts" -i "logop720.png" -filter_complex "[0:0]setsar=1/1,yadif[mvid]; [mvid][1:v]overlay=80:653 [mvid]" -r 25 -refs 5 -vcodec nvenc_hevc -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v -g 25 -sc_threshold 0 -aspect 1280:720 -b:v 3000k -minrate 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 3000k -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 22050 -ac 2 -ab 96k -sn -threads 0 -mpegts_copyts 1 -metadata title="InStat Football videolibrary" -metadata artist="vcoder" -map "[mvid"] -map 0:1 -f segment -segment_list "out2.m3u8" -segment_time 60 -segment_start_number 0 -segment_format mpegts -flags -global_header "out%%06d.ts"`

but get the error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for  '25'
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I change the command to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Your profile:v option is missing its argument.

Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=nvenc_hevc | grep -A 5 profile` to get the list of available values.

Comment: And `-map "[mvid"]` should be `-map "[mvid]"`.